# MinimumPooling in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, max-pooling

I have only found `MaxPooling2D` and `AveragePooling2D` in keras with tensorflow backend. Have been looking for `MinimumPooling2D`. This github [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2816) suggests to use something like this for minimum pooling (`pool2d(-x)`)

I get an error while using a negative sign before inputs. The following line I use in keras

```
MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(-inputs)
```

Comment: I would read further down in the thread you linked to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not sufficient to negate the input argument of the `MaxPooling2D` layer because the pooled values are going to be negative that way.

I think it's better for you to actually implement a general `MinPooling2D` class whose pooling function gets the same parameters as Keras `MaxPooling2D` class and operates analogously. By inheriting from `MaxPooling2D`, the implementation is very simple:

```python
from keras import layers
from keras import backend as K

class MinPooling2D(layers.MaxPooling2D):


  def __init__(self, pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, 
               padding='valid', data_format=None, **kwargs):
    super(MaxPooling2D, self).__init__(pool_size, strides, padding,
                                       data_format, **kwargs)

  def pooling_function(inputs, pool_size, strides, padding, data_format):
    return -K.pool2d(-inputs, pool_size, strides, padding, data_format,
                                                         pool_mode='max')
```

Now you can use this layer just as you would a `MaxPooling2D` layer. For instance, here's an example of how to use `MinPooling2D` layer in a simple sequntial convolutional neural network:

```python
from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MinPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Not sure if i'm the only one, but after running it in colab I got an error regarding the pooling : TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/conv_utils.py in normalize_tuple(value, n, name)
     71     try:
---> 72       value_tuple = tuple(value)
     73     except TypeError:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2):

Using Keras with TF you can just do it by by using the `MaxPooling2D()`. You multiply the input feature maps by `-1`, perform the `MaxPooling2D()` and then, re-multiply the output by `-1` again. Here how to do it:

```
 min_pool = -tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()(-input_features)
```